# Moving a sprite by touching anywhere on the screen

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone, uitouch

In my game only one sprite responds to touches. How can I make a mousejoint move this sprite/body regardless of where I touch on the screen?

Comment: just always return yes in the touch handler. Usually in the touch handler, you check the touch bounds before allowing the touch to be processed, but you can just return yes always, and process the touch as you were.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

mySprite.position = location;

}
```

Make sure in your `init`method that `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`